# vscodeのターミナルが出ない

Tags: ubuntu, vscode

## 現象

vscodeのターミナルが以下のような状態となり表示されません。

[image: vscode画面]

赤字の部分の"既定のシェルの選択"にてbashを選んでも変化はなく、"1:"の表示のままターミナルが表示されない状態が続きます。

vscodeの再インストールを行いましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。

ターミナルを表示させる方法を教えて下さい。

## バージョン情報

### os

```
> cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
```

### vscode

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。

一度snapによってインストールされていたものをアンインストールし、
公式サイトのdebパッケージからaptでインストールを行うとターミナルが表示されるようになりました。

(snapで入れたものもaptで入れたものも、vscodeのバージョンは同一でしたので、ターミナルが表示されなかった根本的な原因は不明です)